# Run android app on device, official android instructions worthless

Tags: android, testing

So I've built a small app and am trying to run it on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

I'm following the instructions on this page: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

However I hit a snag when trying to install the USB driver, as per this page: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html. First of all, in my device manager, I find a device under portable devices which has the name of the phone ("GT-I9300") however there's nothing under the Other Devices section (I only see: "Universal Serial Bus (USB) Controller" and "USB2.0-CRW"). I am unsure as to whether I should be updating the device under portable devices or if the device I'm looking for is missing altogether.

The second problem is that the instructions tell me to look for the driver update in the \extras\google\usb_driver folder. However google is missing from my extras folder. All I have under extras is an android folder which does not contain any drivers.

So what am I supposed to do? The official documentation is worthless. I can only turn to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Samsung Galaxy S3, and the documentation for drivers states that:

```
If your device is one of the Android Developer Phones (purchased from the Google Play
Developer Console), a Nexus One, or a Nexus S, then you need the Google USB Driver,
instead of an OEM driver. The Galaxy Nexus driver, however, is distributed by Samsung
(listed as model SCH-I515).
```

You should therefore install the Samsung drivers for your phone from the [Samsung site](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads) as stated in the documentation. Then you will be able to turn on the correct settings and develop on your phone.

You only need the Google Drivers if you have a Nexus phone.

The extras/google/usb_drivers are installed from the SDK Manager app which you get when you install the Android SDK. Right down the bottom in 'Extras' you will see the `Google USB Driver` which you should install if you use a Nexus phone to develop.